# Reshaping a dataframe with partial aggregation

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, transpose

I have read several questions similar to mine but none actually answered my dilemma (so to speak). I have a dataset composed of 2 columns: on the first column there are x numbers of usernames repeated 100 times each (i.e. if there are 4 usernames these generates 400 rows under a column named "user") and under column 2 there are non-unique strings corresponding to each username. I want to transpose the UNIQUE usernames from rows to columns but maintaining all the values in col2 without aggregation. For simplicity I add below a small sample from iris dataset. In essence I would like to reshape this:

```
Species Petal.Width
setosa         0.2
setosa         0.2
setosa         0.4
versicolor     1.4
versicolor     1.3
versicolor     1.0
```

To this:

```
setosa  versicolor
0.2       1.4
0.2       1.3
0.4       1.0
```

without having to manually subsetting the data, as there will be several usernames and the code may be tediously long to complete. It is actually a replacement of columns (from Species to setosa and versicolor in the example above). Could someone please let me know if there is a quick way to achieve this result?  Thanks!

Comment: Please don't put screen shots. It is really a bad way to share data.

Comment: In addition to the answers in the link: `unstack(d, Petal.Width ~ Species)`

Comment: Hi Henrik, as per your request I will be happy to edit my question, but can you please pinpoint the link where the question I asked was answered? I ran through different forums but none of the proposed answers (including transpose functions, merge, cast, etc.) solved my issue which was brilliantly answered by www. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` and `tidyr` to convert the data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(Species, Petal.Width) %>%
  select(-ID)
dat2
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   setosa versicolor
#    <dbl>      <dbl>
# 1    0.2        1.4
# 2    0.2        1.3
# 3    0.4        1
```

**Data**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Species Petal.Width
setosa         0.2
                  setosa         0.2
                  setosa         0.4
                  versicolor     1.4
                  versicolor     1.3
                  versicolor     1.0",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks www. That was 100% appropriate. dat2 did the job and I had no prior knowledge of those mutate and spread functions. The only addition I made was to add the line as.data.frame(dat2). Thank you!